# Subtraction working in JS but Addition is not working in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to figure out why the subtraction is working in my code, but when I change the subtraction sign to an addition sign, I get a console error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. Where is the error?

Here is a fiddle with the subtraction: http://jsfiddle.net/c8q7p6ac/
Here is a fiddle with the addition in place of the subtraction sign: http://jsfiddle.net/c8q7p6ac/1/

The subtraction sign and the addition sign are in the variable updatedNumber

HTML:

```
<div class="amount">$1000.00</div>

<input class="new-number" type="text">
<div class="button">Click</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
        //get value of input
        var newNumber = $('.new-number').val();

        //get total number value
        var totalNumber = $('.amount').text();

        var getNumberOnly = totalNumber.indexOf('$') + 1;

        var newTotalNumb = totalNumber.substr(getNumberOnly,    totalNumber.length);

        //add new number to total number
        var updatedNumber = (newTotalNumb + newNumber).toFixed(2);


        //and update total
        $('.amount').html('$'+updatedNumber);
});
```

Comment: You have to convert the number from a string to an integer before you can add to it.

Comment: That does make sense, but why will it subtract without having to convert the number form a string to an integer?

Comment: it has to do with the way javascript handles `-` and `+` when using them on mixed types. @Mrchief explains more in-depth.

Comment: A good way to debug this kind of thing is to just Try It And See™. Use `console.log(someVar)` to see the output to find out where one of your variables doesn't match your expected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subtraction works because JavaScript converts them to numbers. However, in case of addition, it converts them to strings as soon as one of the operands is a string.

You need to convert the string to a number:

```
var updatedNumber = (parseInt(newTotalNumb) + parseInt(newNumber)).toFixed(2);
```

While dealing with decimal points, you can also use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) which will preserve the decimal points.

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8q7p6ac/3/).

Comment: What if I am needing to use decimals. It doesnt seem to add those. It rounds to xx.00

Comment: Use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of `parseInt` in that case.